# scala> val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveVariableSource

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am trying to run my access hive table over spark
  Currently using CDH5.4 and hive version is 1.1 and Spark is 1.6
  I have already copied the hive-site.xml file to  spark conf folder.
  if I am trying to run below code getting the error.

**I am trying to get HiveContext so that I can access hive tables in Spark shell**

```
 import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
 import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
 import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

 val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount")
 val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
```

getting error on below line :-

```
scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveVariableSource
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:33)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:44)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:46)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:48)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:50)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:52)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:54)
    at <init>(<console>:56)
    at .<init>(<console>:60)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1045)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1326)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:821)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1064)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveVariableSource
```

**Updated below based on reply on HADOOP_CLASSPATH**

I am using the CDH 5.4 , looks like HADOOP_CLASSPATH is not set

```
cloudera@quickstart ~]$ echo "Classpath=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH" 
  Classpath=
```

But below classpath gave me some output . Do I need my HADOOP_CLASSPATH or its fine  ?

```
   cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop classpath 

/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/./:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/.//*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//*
```

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: My final objective is to use hive table in spark sql but to do I need a object of HiveContext but the below statement is failing in doing so     <br/>                                                          
                val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

Comment: What is the value of Hadoop class path here

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Val SC = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
Then use your piece of code to create hivecontext

Comment: Thanks for the comments @Chandan  ---I tried the                                             
            scala> val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)     ---.This statement got executed successfully but again fot error on  hivecontext   ---
sc: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@3cff58ec

scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveVariableSource
 at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:35)

Comment: Let me try, get back to you

Comment: The code is correct please try set the variable export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HASOOP_CLASSPATH:provide your hive library path.

Comment: I have updated my reply about HADOOP_CLASSPATH at the end of question as comment is not readable.

Comment: `val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf) ` is not the correct way. `val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)` is the correct syntax